# Go - net.LookupAddr doesn't execute

Tags: network-programming, go

Before I added the feature to accept a input address all works fine.

After splitting of the IP-Address into 3 segments and surrender it to the `getHostName` function, the program skips "all/inclusive of the function" after the call of the function `net.LookupAddr(ip)`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func getHostName(h chan string, ipAdresse string, n int) {
    ip := ipAdresse + strconv.Itoa(n)

    addr, ok := net.LookupAddr(ip)
    fmt.Println(ok)

    if ok == nil {
        h <- ip + " - " + addr[0]
    } else {
        fmt.Println(ok)
    }
}

func printer(n chan string) {
    msg := <-n
    fmt.Println(msg)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Please enter your local IP-Adresse e.g 192.168.1.1")

    var ipAdresse_user string
    fmt.Scanln(&ipAdresse_user)

    ipsegment := strings.SplitAfter(ipAdresse_user, ".")
    ipadresse_3 := ipsegment[0] + ipsegment[1] + ipsegment[2]

    host := make(chan string)

    for i := 0; i < 55; i++ {

        go getHostName(host, ipadresse_3, i)
        go printer(host)
    }

    fmt.Println("Finish - Network Scan")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake i have to block the main function with e.g Scanln. Without it the program terminates before the goroutines can be executed.

Comment: You could solve that with a WaitGroup: http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#example_WaitGroup

Comment: You could use a select statement with a timeout: http://play.golang.org/p/fSW0dMTABc